# Recommendation a GPU upgrade for old computer

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, gaming, pc

I am currently building a new PC so I'm looking to give away my previous self build from 2011'ish to the kids. What I was wondering is would a modern graphics card, say something like a GTX 1660Ti be suitable for a GPU upgrade. I see from the spec that it still supports PCIe v3.

Will the old CPU & Memory bottleneck the GTX 1660Ti significantly? If I decide to refresh the custom look would a decent overclock help?

**Spec**

- CPU : Core i7-2700K
- Motherboard : Asus Rampage Gene IV (PCIe 3)
- Memory : 16GB DDR3
- GPU : GTX 580
- Storage : SSD & HDD
- PSU : Corsair HX1050
- Custom Water cooling loop (CPU & GPU) - Needs some work.

Comment: Here's a comparison   https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-580-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1660-Ti/3150vs4037 Clearly the 1660 ti is way faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I am using an i5-4460 (similar to your 2700k in performance I believe) with a 6 GB GTX 1060 and have not noticed any issues playing Far Cry 5 (which is about the only recent AAA I played) or any other games on a 2560x1080 screen. The only game which forced me to fiddle with graphics settings was GTA V. I have been forced to enable FPS capping in Divinity: Original Sin 2 due to alt-tab issues.

You *might* notice issues with a higher resolution display.

The only time I noticed a real CPU bottleneck was when rendering 3D scenes using CUDA in Blender Cycles.

Comment: @PhilMurray you're welcome. Do note that Vulkan and DX12 make CPU performance less relevant as they support multithreading, unlike earlier DirectX and OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

recent member and new as well, but reading about the GTX 1660 Ti, it looks to pretty compatible with most new motherboards, the GTX 1660 Ti uses a single PCIe 3.0 slot at x8 or x16 depending on your system (the longer slots if you're wondering). You can Use AMD and Intel so the difference is not noticeable. I am building a new system and look forward to sharing more information

Comment: Hi @Olabisi. Thanks for the response but the question was more around will the older i7 2700K processor bottleneck the GTX 1660Ti. From what I can see the GPU is compatible with the motherboard but not sure if it's worth the upgrade.

Comment: I apology, I was so broad with my answer.